# JavaScript Replace String with a Character |

Tags: javascript

when I try the following it doesn't work: `str.replace("| stuff", "")`

But if I remove the PIPE it does? `str.replace("stuff", "")`

Why doesn't the JS function allow for the PIPE | ? What can I do to do a replace that includes a pipe?

Comment: what is str, what is your result, and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it

```
"xyz| stuff".replace("\| stuff", ""); //returns xyz
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `.replace` accepts a RegExp, and `|` is a special character in RegExp. You need to escape it.

For example, use `str.replace(/\|/g, "")` to remove every `|` character.

Comment: Thanks but I want to replace the following String " | stuff" There will just be one pipe, how can I replace both?

Comment: a regexp was not used in the example in the question, so no need to escape it

Answer (score 3):

No, it should be working, unless you use `/| stuff/` or `RegExp("| stuff")` instead of `"| stuff"`

```
"xyz| stuff".replace("| stuff", ""); //returns xyz
```

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right. I should have tested before answering.

Comment: @S.Mark, just tested it and it works in IE6+, Firefox 2.0+, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace("| stuff", "")` should work but will only replace the first occurrence.  If you want to replace all of them, try a using a regex like `str.replace(/\|\sstuff/g, "")`

Comment: Or just `str.replace(/\| stuff/g, "")`, but the `\s` makes it work for any whitespace character